# Custom X Axis in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have some data, and one of the Values I have is 'version'.

I would like to use something like the histogram, but instead of each bar being by data, I want it to be by the 'version' value.

How can I build a graph like that in Kibana?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can customize your X axis with a terms panel. Add a new `terms` panel, in the `parameters` select `terms_stats`.

[image: Adding terms panel]

In the `Field` you can select what is going to be in X axis and in `Value Field` you can select the field that is going to be in the Y axis.

This panel has some limitations, like you can only select discrete values, so if your X axis value is a continuous one, you can not show something like that using Kibana. But for discrete values work smoothly.

Comment: Thanks! I actually had a co-worker provide this exact answer!

Comment: This answer does not work on Kibana 6.3. I believe the terms panel went away with Kibana 5.