# How to create own x-axis and y-axis in Kibana?

Tags: dashboard, kibana

I want to have my own field in x-axis and y-axis for a dashboard in kibana? Is it possible?
I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687826/custom-x-axis-in-kibana), but does not help! Could anyone please guide me to get this.

I am able to create custom x-axis & y -axis but i need to show two fields which is associated with one field on x axis as a value on y axis. i have attached sample data.[image]
Thanks in Advance

And the Dashboard i need to show looks like.
[image]

The Dashboard i am able to get is[image]

Comment: Why does the other post not help?  What about your problem is different?  Just saying, this worked for him but not for me, isn't helpful for us.  We can't guide you if we don't know why you are derailed.

Comment: @Walls I followed steps mentioned in the post to have my field as x-axis and y-axis but getting nothing as result. It shows a big 0 in place of bar/table.

Comment: @user3490564 Could you detail more your problem? Screenshots and examples with data that you have in your ES cluster could be helpful for us to help you.

Comment: @Pigueiras Sorry, actually i meant it works for x-axis & y axis, But i need a way to show two fields's value datewise. Details updated in question.Thanks

Comment: @user3490564 It is not possible at the moment to do that sorry :(. You can not put multiple values in a graph in Kibana (a very request missing feature of Kibana as you can see in https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/pull/374).